# Обработка схожих переменных в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть некоторое количество переменных записанных как: х_1, х_2, ... х7.

```
x_1 = '1'
x_2 = '2'
x_3 = '3'
x_4 = '4'
x_5 = '5'
x_6 = '6'
x_7 = '7'

for i in range(1,8):
    a = 'x_' + str(i)
    print(a)
```

Мне известно их имя, но собирать 600+ переменных в список не очень хочется.
Есть ли какой-то более простой вариант как вывести их все?

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, что вы хотите получить? Вывести можно их и по вашему коду, все работает.

Comment: Если 600+, то именно через список. Если вы так и будете цепляться за "не хочется" и игнорировать общепринятые практики, то далеко в программировании вы так не продвинитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
x_1 = '1'
x_2 = '2'
x_3 = '3'
x_4 = '4'
x_5 = '5'
x_6 = '6'
x_7 = '7'

MAX_X = 7

for i in range(1, MAX_X+1):
    print(globals()[f'x_{i}'])
```